# PHP & Mysql - Left Outer Join between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, polymorphic-associations

I have two tables called 'events' and 'topics' each table can have many comments.

What I need to do is list all the events and topics with the amount of comments for each row. I've managed to return all the topics, which works great but I don't know how I can add the events table to the MySql. The comments and events table fields are listed below. Can anyone help me with this query?

Events:

- ID
- Event_Name

Comments:

- post_id <-- the releated id for either the events or topics table
- table <-- The table that the row belongs to so either topics or events

  ```
  SELECT 
    t.id, t.title, c.created_at, 
    IF(ISNULL(c.allComments), 0, c.allComments) AS totalComments
  FROM topics AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT created_at, post_id, COUNT(*) AS allComments 
      FROM comments
      GROUP BY post_id
  ) AS c ON c.post_id = t.id
  ORDER BY tc.created_at DESC, c.allComments DESC
  ```

Comment: This is an example of a [Polymorphic Association](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/polymorphic-associations/hot) which is considered a SQL Anti-Pattern (See [Bill Karwin's book: SQL Antipatterns](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) for more information.  I'd suggest a redesign of the table schema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like events and topics should be the same table.

Still, I think we can do this with a UNION.  Events and Topics have the same columns i hope?  (Or at least the same important ones?)

```
(SELECT c.table as event_or_topic, e.*, count(C.table), MAX(C.created_at) as latest_c
FROM events E LEFT JOIN comments C on (C.post_id = E.id)
WHERE C.table = 'Events' 
GROUP BY C.post_id)
UNION
(SELECT c.table as event_or_topic, t.id*, count(C.table), MAX(C.created_at) as latest_c
FROM topics T LEFT JOIN comments C on (C.post_id = E.id)
WHERE C.table = 'Topics' 
GROUP BY C.post_id)
ORDER BY latest_c
```

Notice that the ORDER BY applies to the whole UNION, not the individual SELECTs.

The use of LEFT JOIN should allow those rows without Comments to still show.  I think the problem is that we have parts of our select dependent on comments (ie - C.table, ordering on last comment, etc).  The count should be fine - will just be zero if there are no comments.

You might need to change the SELECT part slightly.  I'd like to display C.table so you know whether a row is a topic or event, but im afraid it might screw up the count.  Do you need anything from comments besides the count?  You use some columns other than post_id and table in your query that you neglected to explain in your question.

You still have columns I don't know what they are, like Comment's zoneTable

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your help. I need it to also display everything in the events and topics table. At the moment it only displays an event or topic if it has a comment(s). Also I need to order it by the latest comment - C.created_at. Would have any idea how I can add this in?

Comment: by the way this is my lastest mysql.

SELECT e.id, e.title, C.zoneTable, count(C.zoneTable)
FROM events E
LEFT JOIN comments C on (C.post_id = E.id)
 WHERE C.zoneTable = 'Events' 
 GROUP BY C.post_id
UNION
SELECT t.id, t.title, C.zoneTable, count(C.zoneTable)
FROM topics T 
LEFT JOIN comments C on (C.post_id = t.ID)
 WHERE C.zoneTable = 'topics' 
 GROUP BY C.post_id
LIMIT 25

Comment: Thanks again Jon. c.zoneTable is the table that the comment is related to. So c.table is c.zoneTable. Ok I'm getting the ordering now but still not showing all the events or topics only the ones that have a comment.

Comment: Here is the latest: (SELECT c.zoneTable as event_or_topic, e.ID, e.title, count(C.zoneTable), MAX(C.created_at) as latest_c
FROM Events e LEFT JOIN comments C on (C.post_id = e.ID)
WHERE C.zoneTable = 'events' 
GROUP BY C.post_id)
UNION
(SELECT c.zoneTable as event_or_topic, t.ID, t.title, count(C.zoneTable), MAX(C.created_at) as latest_c
FROM topics t LEFT JOIN comments C on (C.post_id = t.ID)
WHERE C.zoneTable = 'topics' 
GROUP BY C.post_id)
ORDER BY latest_c DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT 
t.id, t.title, c.created_at, COUNT(c.allComments) AS totalComments
FROM topics AS t LEFT JOIN comments c ON t.id=c.post_id
GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY tc.created_at DESC, c.allComments DESC`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you have 3 tables:

-Events

-Topics

-Comments

If that is true something like this should extract all the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM events,topics
LEFT JOIN comments ON post_ID = ID
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Hope i'm along the right lines!

W.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. If anyone knows of a better and an efficient way of doing this, then please let me know:

```
(SELECT t.id, t.title, tc.dateCreated AS commentDate, 
IF(ISNULL(tc.allComments), 0, tc.allComments) AS totalComments,
t.LastActive as dateChanged
    FROM Events AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT MAX(created_at) AS dateCreated, post_id,
          COUNT(*) AS allComments 
          FROM comments
          GROUP BY post_id
          ) AS tc ON tc.post_id = t.id)
UNION
(SELECT t.id, t.title, tc.dateCreated AS commentDate, 
IF(ISNULL(tc.allComments), 0, tc.allComments) AS totalComments,
t.LastActive as dateChanged 
    FROM topics AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT MAX(created_at) AS dateCreated, post_id,
          COUNT(*) AS allComments 
          FROM comments
          GROUP BY post_id
          ) AS tc ON tc.post_id = t.id)
ORDER BY commentDate DESC, dateChanged DESC, totalComments DESC
```